# Passing Table data as JSON Object and processing that in jsp or servlet

Tags: java

I have a table in my html code. It's rows varies based on user input (by using jquery append method). Now After user clicks on save button I want to send the data stored in input fields to server via json object (because I don't know how many rows that the user had added to my table and what data does it has?).

Is there any way in jquery or ajax to parse a table as JSON object to a servlet and reading that json object in servlet and store it's value in mysql data base.

Comment: you'll need to give us more details of the FORM element

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled this was a bit crude but it works.
I had a grid where the number of rows can grow.So on addition of every row by the user,I do some pre-processing to prevent duplicate entry etc(validation) and then build up a semi-colon separated string for every row.I use columns to separate every column in a given row.
I **keep building this string and assign it to my hidden form field**.
On the server side I use a tokenzier to deal with it in the right fashion.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way, you can create JSON Array with an entry for each column, and fill this array into an array of rows. On serverside you could deserialize this objects with a json to Java Parser like GSON or [Jackson](http://software.danielwatrous.com/restful-java-servlet-serializing-tofrom-json-with-jackson/). I't needs a defined Modell, witch in your case look like (only as example):

```
public class JSONModelForTable{
    private List<List<String>> rows;

    public List<List<String>> getRows){
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(<List<List>> rows){
        this.rows=rows;
    }
}
```